# Running flask in Python

Tags: python, flask

I am new to python and started with learning with spyder IDE.
I was trying to run flask application in spyder but looks like I am making some mistakes while running it. Can anyone help me ?

[image]

If you see the above image... When I run app.py, i get error message as "No module names flask". But when I see flask version , i get 2.2.2 (meaning flask is already there). Then why I am getting this error?

I already installed flask in terminal

[image]

Comment: I have already installed flask in my terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have several versions of Python

First try this :

Comment lines 9 and 10

Create a new terminal in the path of the file and type this:

```
flask run
```

If this does not work, you can create a virtual environment in Python and install Flask in it

Answer (score 1):

The `!flask` command goes over your shell and calls `flask.exe` inside `\Anaconda\Scripts` this should work for every environment(?)

`import flask` goes over your current environment in which flask is not installed according to the error.

Did you create a new environment and run spyder from there?
If you open anaconda console -> python -> import flask
What happens then?

Rare chance that this is an error with your PATH but probably just the missing installation for the environment.